# Firestore Throw Handle Exception Error crash in Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

My app keeps crashing after submitting a comment. I believe the crash is occurring when Firebase goes to retrieve the comment data to display it. This only happens when trying to submit a comment. It doesn't happen when I post a photo or like any post. So I can't figure out why I'm only having a Firestore issue there.

**Here's my Flutter configuration:**

```
(base) Indigos-MacBook-Pro:buddies_gram indigoguerra$ flutter doctor -v
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.17.4, on Mac OS X 10.15 19A603, locale en-US)
    • Flutter version 1.17.4 at /Users/indigoguerra/Documents/flutter
    • Framework revision 1ad9baa8b9 (12 days ago), 2020-06-17 14:41:16 -0700
    • Engine revision ee76268252
    • Dart version 2.8.4

 
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 28.0.3)
    • Android SDK at /Users/indigoguerra/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-29, build-tools 28.0.3
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_202-release-1483-b49-5587405)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 11.1)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Xcode 11.1, Build version 11A1027
    • CocoaPods version 1.9.3

[✓] Android Studio (version 3.5)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin version 43.0.1
    • Dart plugin version 191.8593
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_202-release-1483-b49-5587405)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.45.1)
    • VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension version 3.11.0

[✓] Connected device (2 available)
    • Android SDK built for x86 • emulator-5554                        • android-x86 • Android 9 (API 28) (emulator)
    • iPhone 11 Pro Max         • B133739C-30C8-4C46-A545-7E94D7BAB5A4 • ios         • com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-13-1 (simulator)

• No issues found!
```

**Here's my pubspec.yaml dependencies:**

```
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.1.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  cloud_firestore: ^0.13.7
  image: ^2.0.7
  animator: 0.1.4
  image_picker: ^0.6.0+2
  google_sign_in: ^4.0.1+1
  timeago: 2.0.17
  cached_network_image:
  firebase_auth: ^0.16.1
  geolocator: 5.0.1
  uuid: ^2.0.0
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
  path_provider: ^0.5.0+1
  firebase_messaging: ^4.0.0+1
  firebase_storage: ^3.1.6
  flutter_image_compress: ^0.6.8
  image_cropper: ^1.2.2
  flutter_svg:
```

**This is the error I get:**

```
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23baa1ee __exceptionPreprocess + 350
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff50864b20 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   Runner                              0x00000001067317b5 _ZN8firebase9firestore4util16ObjcThrowHandlerENS1_13ExceptionTypeEPKcS4_iRKNSt3__112basic_stringIcNS5_11char_traitsIcEENS5_9allocatorIcEEEE + 581
    3   Runner                              0x0000000106730cf3 _ZN8firebase9firestore4util5ThrowENS1_13ExceptionTypeEPKcS4_iRKNSt3__112basic_stringIcNS5_11char_traitsIcEENS5_9allocatorIcEEEE + 67
    4   Runner                           <…>
```

**This is the function that saves the comment:**

```
saveComment(){
    commentsReference.document(postId).collection("comments").add({
      "username": currentUser.username,
      "comment": commentTextEditingController.text,
      "timestamp": DateTime.now(),
      "url": currentUser.url,
      "userId": currentUser.id,
    });

    bool isNotPostOwner = postOwnerId != currentUser.id;
    if(isNotPostOwner) {
      activityFeedReference.document(postOwnerId).collection("feedItems").add({
        "type": "comment",
        "commentDate": timestamp,
        "postId": postId,
        "userId": currentUser.id,
        "username": currentUser.username,
        "userProfileImg": currentUser.url,
        "url": postImageUrl,
      });
    }
    commentTextEditingController.clear();
  }
```

Can someone please help me resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. It was completely my fault.
I had

```
CommentsPageState createState() => CommentsPageState(postId: postId, postOwnerId: postImageUrl, postImageUrl: postImageUrl);
```

Instead of

```
CommentsPageState createState() => CommentsPageState(postId: postId, postOwnerId: postOwnerId, postImageUrl: postImageUrl);
```

So it was getting the postImageUrl link instead of the postOwnerId